# Why is `slot.assignedNodes({flatten: true})` not detecting the default `<div>` in the slot?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element

I just spent many minutes trying to debug this issue. I found no source documenting this behavior ― maybe I missed them if they do exist ― and I decided to write this here in case someone else faces the same issue.

A Web Component I built has a `<slot>` element with a default `<div>` inside of it:

```html
<slot name="timer">
    <div class="rp__timer"></div>
</slot>
```

When I tried to update the `<div>` using `innerHTML` nothing happened. It is as if the `<div>` doesn't exist. Here's how I tried to access the `<div>`:

```js
this.timerSlot = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('slot[name=timer]');
let div = this.timerSlot.assignedNodes({flatten: true})[0];
div.innerHTML = "SOME TEXTE";
```

But nothing is happening. What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM **nodes** are **not** the same as DOM **elements**

```
<p>Hello<a href="">Web Components</a>World</p>
```

Elements **p** and **a** are a **sub-set** of all Nodes

[image]

So **assignedNodes** gives you all **5 Nodes** (`href` in the image is an *attribute*)

and **assignedElements** gives you the **2 Elements** you are after

#### MDN Documentation:

For documentation **always** use MDN (although MDN isn't 100% correct either)

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/assignedNodes
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/assignedElements

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I never knew about the difference between a node and an element. That explains it perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

So here's what's wrong with the code above.

For some reason, the `<div>` I created was not assigned the index 0 in the array returned by `assignNodes()`. It was in fact in case number one. When `console.log()`ed the return value of `this.timerSlot.assignedNodes({flatten: true})` it came as something like this `Array(3) [ #text, div.rp__timer, #text ]` in both Chrome and Firefox.

It turns out the new lines I added for better readability around the `<div>` in the HTML file were not ignored as I believed they would.

After updating my code into a one-line configuration, i.e. `<slot name="timer"><div class="rp__timer"></div></slot>`, the problem disappeared and the code did what it was expected to do.

Now, I don't know it this is a feature or a bug. But since it was present in both Chrome and Firefox I assume it maybe the former. Either way, I was unable to find in the available documentation any mention of it.

I hope you'd find this useful.